# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable with list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created a function that accepts a list of numbers to be reversed.

```
def getListBackward(number):
    reversedNumbers = number[::-1] #line with error
    '''
    code that does stuff with reversed numbers below
    '''
EDIT:
```

this is the function that calls the getListBakcward

```
def sumofreversed(numbers):
    total = getListBackward(numbers) + otherlist(numbers)
    return total
```

I obtained numbers by user input and passed it as the parameter.
However, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

What did I do wrong? How can I go about fixing this?

Comment: As the traceback states, number is None. Do you have any more code to show that might help?

Comment: Post the code that calls this function, seems like you are passing `number` incorrectly.

Comment: The error is in the code that calls `getListBackward` with a value that's `None` instead of a list. Or, possibly, in the code that `getListBackward` calls that returns a `None`, or the code that calls it and passes it a `None`. You have to figure out where in your code you ended up getting a `None` when you expected a list.

Comment: @ODiogoSilva that would give a different type error (`'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`)

Comment: @wim, you made me double check, but no. If `number` is None trying to reverse the string will raise a TypeError exception

Comment: Can you post all traceback?

Comment: Oh, whoops, on python3 it will be the one about subscriptable.  On python2 it would be about `__getitem__`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not return the reversed list back to the called, and the function will return `None` as a default value, try to return the value:

```
>>> def getListBackward(number):
...   return number[::-1]
>>> def sumofreversed(numbers):
...   total = getListBackward(numbers) + [1,2,3]
...   return total
>>> alist = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> print getListBackward(alist)
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
>>> print sumofreversed(alist)
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Will be ok.

Comment: def getListBackward(number) function already returns a list at the end. That's why I'm kinda confused as to why it's giving me this error. :(

Comment: Is that possible you give the function an empty list, so that it return a `[]` ?just print out the value it return.

Comment: I don't even think it's returning any value because it's getting stuck at that line of code. =\

Comment: Can you post the traceback info so that we find out why it's wrong?